# Conditionally include a pipe stage in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've got a script like the following:

```
flag=false
# Do a bunch of stuff that might set flag to true.
if [[ "$flag" == "true" ]]; then
   command \
       | pipe_command_a \
       | pipe_command_b \
       | pipe_command_c \
       | pipe_command_d \
       > "${output_path}"
else
   command \
       | pipe_command_a \
       | pipe_command_c \
       | pipe_command_d \
       > "${output_path}"
fi
```

The only difference between `flag` being `true` or `false` makes is that `pipe_command_b` may not be run. Is there a way to collapse this so that I don't have to repeat all of the common stuff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `cat` instead of the command if you want to skip it:

```
command=cat
if [[ $flag == true ]] ; then
    command=pipe_command_b
fi
command \
    | pipe_command_a \
    | $command       \
    | pipe_command_c
```

Comment: Isn't it possible that piping cat into certain commands may break things?

Comment: @Jesse_b: They seem to pipe the output to pipe_command_c anyway.

Comment: yea but cat also changes some results.  The only one I can think of now is `ls` which you wouldn't want to use in a pipeline anyway but `ls | cat` provides a different result than just `ls`

Comment: @Jesse_b: Still the same reply. The only problem with that is when the command is the last one in the pipeline.

Comment: @Jesse_b that isn't `cat` "changing some results".   That's `ls` detecting that its stdout is not a tty and producing different output (i.e. one filename per line rather than multiple filenames on multi-column line(s)).