# Calling a function within a pipe

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, function

I have a script using a pretty long pipe quite a lot of times.
The middle of each pipe is the same command chain. Only the beginning and the end defers all the time it is used.

```
Different-command-1 |
 command A |
 command B |
 command C |
 diff-cmd-2
```

is there a way to call this commands as a function within the pipe?
Like:

```
same-commands() {
    command A |
    command B |
    command C 
}

Different-command-1 |
 same-commands |
 diff-cmd-2

Different-command-3 |
 same-commands |
 diff-cmd-4
```

this in my case would save quite a lot of lines in my script, but I can not quite figure out how this could work.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383738/conditionally-include-a-pipe-stage-in-a-bash-script & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38310/conditional-pipeline

Comment: But as the function will just run the commands within it with the same stdin and stdout, you should be able to do `func() { foo | bar; }` and then use `func` in place of `foo | bar`

Comment: @ilkkachu I do not quite understand what I'm doing wrong, I allways get `syntax error near unexpected token ('` maybe I should come up with a real MWE that could run...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands in a function run with the same stdin and stdout as the function itself, so we can just put a pipeline in a function, and the stick the function in another pipeline, as it if were any other command:

```
func() { 
    tr a x | 
    tr b x
}
echo abc | func | tr c x
```

This prints `xxx`.

Comment: thanks that works for me! also nice using the slash at the end of the line and saving the line-break.

Comment: @nath, yeah, there's no special syntax for a pipeline in a function, the outer pipeline doesn't really need to know if one of the commands is a function instead of something else.

Comment: @nath, and yes, backslashes are ugly :( Also, with `foo() { ... }`, you don't want to have a backslash before the closing `}`, the syntax requires a newline or a semicolon there.